# Adding Child Nodes to a Treeview from DataTable (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, nodes

I'm having a hard time trying to get a Treeview to display child notes.

I have a DataTable which is filled with Data from a query.

The table is something like this.

```
| ParentOT | ChildOT
  -------------------
  1        | 2
  1        | 3
  1        | 4
  4        | 5
  5        | 6
```

now, what I need is to order this data in a TreeView.

The result must be something like this (using this same table)

```
1
|
--2
|
--3
|
--4
  |
  --5
    |
    --6
```

I tried to this on Windows Forms and the only thing I can get is the tree to show only 1 set of childs. like this

```
1
|
--2
|
--3
|
--4
|
--5
|
5
|
--6
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
DataTable arbolSub = mssql_cnn.ejecutarSqlSelect(q2);

            //Metodo 2: muestra las ot correctamente pero no muestra mas detalle de subOT.
            if (trvOTHs.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                trvOTHs.Nodes.Clear();
            }

            trvOTHs.BeginUpdate();

            if (arb.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string otPadre = arb.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                int nivel = 0;

                trvOTHs.Nodes.Add(arbolSub.Rows[0]["OT Padre"].ToString());

                for (int i = 0; i < arbolSub.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //trvOTHs.Nodes.Add(arbolSub.Rows[0]["OT Padre"].ToString());                  
                    if (arbolSub.Rows[i]["OT Padre"].ToString() == otPadre)
                    {
                        if (trvOTHs.Nodes[nivel].Text == otPadre)
                        {
                            trvOTHs.Nodes[nivel].Nodes.Add(arbolSub.Rows[i]["OT Hija"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        otPadre = arbolSub.Rows[i+1]["OT Padre"].ToString();
                        TreeNode nodo = new TreeNode(otPadre.ToString());
                        trvOTHs.Nodes.Add(nodo);
                        nivel++;
                    }

                }


                trvOTHs.Nodes[0].Remove();

                trvOTHs.ExpandAll();
            }

            trvOTHs.EndUpdate();
```

where trvOTHs is a TreeView.

Please Help! Thanks

**EDIT**: Thanks for the reply. I finally worked around this,using a idea given by a friend and using something like the suggested solution by @Mohammad abumazen.

I ended up using two methods recursively:

```
 private TreeView cargarOtPadres(TreeView trv, int otPadre, DataTable datos)
    {
        if (datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
            foreach (DataRow dr in datos.Select("OTPadre='"+ otPadre+"'"))
            {
                TreeNode nodoPadre = new TreeNode();
                nodoPadre.Text = dr["OTPadre"].ToString();
                trv.Nodes.Add(nodoPadre);
                cargarSubOts(ref nodoPadre, int.Parse(dr["OTHija"].ToString()), datos);
            }
        }
        return trv;
    }

    private void cargarSubOts(ref TreeNode nodoPadre, int otPadre, DataTable datos)
    {
        DataRow[] otHijas = datos.Select("OTPadre='" + otPadre +"'");
        foreach (DataRow drow in otHijas)
        {
            TreeNode hija = new TreeNode();
            hija.Text = drow["OTHija"].ToString();
            nodoPadre.Nodes.Add(hija);
            cargarSubOts(ref hija, int.Parse(drow["OTHija"].ToString()), datos);
        }
    }
```

This did it. I leave it here in case anyone needs it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in your code that you are not looking for the child parent in the tree view to add it under , you add them all under main parent.

i made some changes to your code hopefully it work straight forward or with minor changes at your side:

```
        if (arb.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            TreeNode MainNode = new TreeNode();

            string otPadre = arb.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            int nivel = 0;

            MainNode.Text = otPadre;
            trvOTHs.Nodes.Add(MainNode);

            for (int i = 0; i < arbolSub.Rows.Count; i++)
            {        

            TreeNode child = new TreeNode();
            child.Text = row["OT Hija"].ToString();

            if (arbolSub.Rows[i]["OT Padre"].ToString() == otPadre)
            {
                MainNode.Nodes.Add(child);  
            }
            else
            {
                FindParent(MainNode, row["OT Padre"].ToString(), child);
            }

            }

            trvOTHs.ExpandAll();
        }
```

this function to find the parent node :

```
    private void FindParent(TreeNode ParentNode, string Parent, TreeNode ChildNode)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in ParentNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (node.Text.ToString() == Parent)
            {
                node.Nodes.Add(ChildNode); 
            }
            else
            {
                FindParent(node, Parent, ChildNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, You should consider using `Dictionary` and `HashSet` for maximum performance:

```
//use this extension method for convenience
public static class TreeViewExtension {
  public static void LoadFromDataTable(this TreeView tv, DataTable dt){
        var parentNodes = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(row => (string)row[0])
                            .ToDictionary(g=> g.Key, value=> value.Select(x=> (string)x[1]));
        Stack<KeyValuePair<TreeNode,IEnumerable<string>>> lookIn = new Stack<KeyValuePair<TreeNode,IEnumerable<string>>>();
        HashSet<string> removedKeys = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var node in parentNodes) {
            if (removedKeys.Contains(node.Key)) continue;
            TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode(node.Key);
            lookIn.Push(new KeyValuePair<TreeNode,IEnumerable<string>>(tNode,node.Value));
            while (lookIn.Count > 0) {
                var nodes = lookIn.Pop();                    
                foreach (var n in nodes.Value) {
                    IEnumerable<string> children;
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(n);
                    nodes.Key.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                    if (parentNodes.TryGetValue(n, out children)) {
                        lookIn.Push(new KeyValuePair<TreeNode,IEnumerable<string>>(childNode,children));
                        removedKeys.Add(n);
                    }
                }
            }
            tv.Nodes.Add(tNode);
        }
    }
}
//usage    
treeView1.LoadFromDataTable(yourDataTable);
```

**NOTE** the input `DataTable` should contain data as you posted in your question. **There is no need for other kinds of Sub-DataTable**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I finally worked around this,using a idea given by a friend and using something like the suggested solution by @Mohammad abumazen.

I ended up using two methods recursively:

```
private TreeView cargarOtPadres(TreeView trv, int otPadre, DataTable datos)
{
    if (datos.Rows.Count > 0)
    { 
        foreach (DataRow dr in datos.Select("OTPadre='"+ otPadre+"'"))
        {
            TreeNode nodoPadre = new TreeNode();
            nodoPadre.Text = dr["OTPadre"].ToString();
            trv.Nodes.Add(nodoPadre);
            cargarSubOts(ref nodoPadre, int.Parse(dr["OTHija"].ToString()), datos);
        }
    }
    return trv;
}

private void cargarSubOts(ref TreeNode nodoPadre, int otPadre, DataTable datos)
{
    DataRow[] otHijas = datos.Select("OTPadre='" + otPadre +"'");
    foreach (DataRow drow in otHijas)
    {
        TreeNode hija = new TreeNode();
        hija.Text = drow["OTHija"].ToString();
        nodoPadre.Nodes.Add(hija);
        cargarSubOts(ref hija, int.Parse(drow["OTHija"].ToString()), datos);
    }
}
```

This did it. I leave it here in case anyone needs it. Thanks again.