# C# treeview getting duplicate nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

By the beginning of this week Iwas having a problem with TreeView not displaying children. Everything got worked out through recursiveness. However, a new and unexpected problem arose: the methods i'm using are getting duplicate nodes on some specific DataTables.

Having this DataTable of two columns:

```
ParentOT    ChildOT
20120601    20120602
20120601    20120603
20120601    20120604
20120601    20120611
20120601    20120612
20120602    20120605
20120602    20120606
20120602    20120607
20120602    20120608
20120602    20120610
20120603    20120607
20120603    20120608
20120603    20120609
```

If I try to display its Treeview I get the right treeview, but five times consecutively (the times the parent appears as parent in parentOT records).

The Methods are these:

```
 private TreeView cargarOtPadres(TreeView trv, int otPadre, DataTable datos)
    {
        if (datos.Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
            foreach (DataRow dr in datos.Select("OTPadre="+ otPadre))
            {
                TreeNode nodoPadre = new TreeNode();
                nodoPadre.Text = dr["OTPadre"].ToString();
                trv.Nodes.Add(nodoPadre);
                cargarSubOts(ref nodoPadre, int.Parse(dr["OTPadre"].ToString()), datos);
            }
        }
        return trv;
    }

    private void cargarSubOts(ref TreeNode nodoPadre, int otPadre, DataTable datos)
    {
        DataRow[] otHijas = datos.Select("OTPadre=" + otPadre);
        foreach (DataRow drow in otHijas)
        {
            TreeNode hija = new TreeNode();
            hija.Text = drow["OTHija"].ToString();
            nodoPadre.Nodes.Add(hija);
            cargarSubOts(ref hija, int.Parse(drow["OTHija"].ToString()), datos);
        }
    }
```

With Tables with just 1 great parent appearing 1 time only, it works great. How can i prevent the TreeView from duplicating??

Comment: my answer to the previous question of yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502975/adding-child-nodes-to-a-treeview-from-datatable-c-windows-forms has been **well tested** BUT you didn't even try it? using your own code makes your stuck now.

Comment: BTW, here's the result I get from my code https://sites.google.com/site/thecabinet3/home/files-store/wtf.png?attredirects=0 isn't that what you want?

Comment: @KingKing I tried your solution now, and it really works well, using it on strings. However, the Datatype of data is int (as well as it is on SQL Server) and not string. I'm trying now to adapt that from your solution. Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm still just a noob around here. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the answer for the sake of completion. This solution came courtesy of @King King

```
public static class TreeViewExtension
{
    public static void LoadFromDataTable(this TreeView tv, DataTable dt)
    {
        var parentNodes = dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(row => (string)row[0])
                            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, value => value.Select(x => (string)x[1]));
        Stack<KeyValuePair<TreeNode, IEnumerable<string>>> lookIn = new Stack<KeyValuePair<TreeNode, IEnumerable<string>>>();
        HashSet<string> removedKeys = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (var node in parentNodes)
        {
            if (removedKeys.Contains(node.Key)) continue;
            TreeNode tNode = new TreeNode(node.Key);
            lookIn.Push(new KeyValuePair<TreeNode, IEnumerable<string>>(tNode, node.Value));
            while (lookIn.Count > 0)
            {
                var nodes = lookIn.Pop();
                foreach (var n in nodes.Value)
                {
                    IEnumerable<string> children;
                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(n);
                    nodes.Key.Nodes.Add(childNode);
                    if (parentNodes.TryGetValue(n, out children))
                    {
                        lookIn.Push(new KeyValuePair<TreeNode, IEnumerable<string>>(childNode, children));
                        removedKeys.Add(n);
                    }
                }
            }
            tv.Nodes.Add(tNode);
        }
    }
}
```

You create this class

And you use afterwards like this.

```
treeView1.LoadFromDataTable(DataTable);
```

Be sure to use it with a String type DataTable. If you have a int type Table, you can do something like this:

```
DataTable stringDataTable = intDataTable.Clone();
           stringDataTable.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(string);
           stringDataTable.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string);

            foreach (DataRow dr in intDataTable.Rows)
            {
                stringDataTable.ImportRow(dr);
            }

treeView1.LoadFromDataTable(stringDataTable);
```